# IntelliSense shows errors but still able to build

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Whenever I change something in any XAML file in my Solution every reference in the Code Behind file will be marked as an error and IntelliSense stops working. but if I build the Solution everything works fine and IntelliSense works. Also just the files which are currently open show this behavior. As soon as I close it the errors disappears.

Should I be worried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you see when opening/editing a XAML are somewhat by design. It *tries* to do a quick test if your markup is valid, but in my experience, especially when using advanced bindings with custom objects, it will fail more often than it doesn't. This check is done to prevent you get errors on run-time, since most of the XAML is run-time evaluated.

So what you should do is check the messages, if you sure they are okay, just continue and see if the code actually works. If you see this error often, just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the code and it works all fine on runtime. But even if I add a new Window it has the same behaviour. And I try to ignore it but programming without IntelliSense is a bit annoying

Comment: It could be something broken in Visual Studio too, so you could try to search for the specific error. It might help, but don't expect too much of it.

Comment: Ya ive experienced the same issue with 2010. 2013 seems a bit better.

Comment: @CathalMF my problem is, that I cannot update my VS because of our toolchain in the company

Comment: What a schame.. thats really annoying